RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument for IPV6 route add
My ISP provided me a leaseline with static IPV6 address, my side is A:B:C:41::2 and the oppsite side is A:B:C:41:1. And also they provided the IP set A:B:C:42:: for the users.
All users are using static IPs.
Here is the interfaces config for IPV6:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::eafc:afff:fefd:ac37/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vlan1@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::eafc:afff:fefd:ac37/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vlan2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 A:B:C:41::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::eafc:afff:fefd:ac38/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::eafc:afff:fefd:ac39/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::eafc:afff:fefd:ac4a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::eafc:afff:fefd:ac5b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
26: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 A:B:C:42::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::eafc:afff:fefd:ac27/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And my router table is below:
A:B:C:41::/64 dev vlan2  metric 256 
A:B:C:42::/64 dev br0  metric 1024 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev vlan1  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev br0  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth1  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth2  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth3  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev vlan2  metric 256 
default via A:B:C:41::1 dev vlan2  metric 1024 
default dev vlan2  metric 2048 
unreachable default dev lo  metric -1  error -101
ff00::/8 dev eth0  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev vlan1  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev br0  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev eth1  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev eth2  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev eth3  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev vlan2  metric 256 
unreachable default dev lo  metric -1  error -101

The vlan2 is used to go outside with the leaseline and br0 is used for the users.
With current configuration, the router can access 41::1 and users with 42::(such as 42::2)
But 42::2 can only access 41::2, 41::1 is not accessable.
Therefore, I try to add a record to routing table
ip -6 route add A:B:C:42::/64 via A:B:C:42::1 dev br0
ip: RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

I try delete the second line of the routing table, and the result is the same.
What should I do?

Why do you think you need this specific route? In particular, how does specifying yourself as a gateway make any logical sense, and how would it differ from the existing automatic subnet route that you have in line 2?

Currently, I disabled radvd and dhcpv6.  Users set 42::1 as gateway. They can not access 41::1.

Ah, are you trying to add the route on clients instead? But those too are supposed to already have a 42::/64 route directly from having a 42::xxx/64 IP address (i.e. being on the subnet).

I hope clints can send packet from 42::XXX/64 IP address -> 42::1 -> 41::2 ->41::1 -> go out.  But now stucks on 41::2, cannot go out with 41::1. So I am a bit confused.

Okay, but what does that have to do with the routes you're trying to add? If the client is trying to send packets to 41::1, wouldn't you be adding a route for 41::/64 or ::/0 instead?

The default route via 41::1 is already on the router table above.
